# Law of large numbers for Markov Chains

Tags: probability, measure-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose we have a Markov Chain $X_n$ on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow [0,1]$ be a measurable function.

Does a law of large numbers hold, i.e. $\frac{f(X_1) +...+f(X_n)}{n} \longrightarrow p\in [0,1]$ in probability or a.s.?

Without the assumption that $f$  is bounded this is clearly not true (since we can take $f(x)=x$ and $X_n$ to be some deterministic increasing Markov Chain), but is this assumption enough?

Comment: You may set $X_n = X_0 + n$ and choose $f$ cleverly so that $(f(X_1)+\cdots+f(X_n))/n$ does not converge. (I guess $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+(-1)^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor})$ would work.)